# Java: Sort entries for table of contents

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to implement a comparator to sort my menu items. They should be sorted like chapters and subchapters. Therefore each item knows its parent. If two or more items have the same parent, it should be sorted after the position number:

```
public class menuItem {
 private menuItem parent;
 private int position;
 (constructor, getters&setters, ...)
}

public ArrayList<menuItem> getMenu(){
  menuItem m1 = new menuItem(null, 0);
  menuItem m1_1 = new menuItem(m1, 0);
  menuItem m1_2 = new menuItem(m1, 1);
  menuItem m1_2_1 = new menuItem(m1_2, 0);
  menuItem m1_2_2 = new menuItem(m1_2, 1);
  menuItem m2 = new menuItem(null, 1);
  menuItem m2_1 = new menuItem(m2, 0);
  menuItem m2_2 = new menuItem(m2, 1);

  ArrayList<menuItem> menu = new ArrayList<>();
  //add all menuItems to menu
  return menu;
}
```

Comparator:

```
@Override
public int compare(menuItem o1, menuItem o2) {
  **?**
}
```

In the code above, all menu items are created in order as they should appear on the page. But how do I sort them if they are added to menu randomly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(All pseudo-code)  For each item, construct a `List<Integer>` which represent the positions, start from root:

```
List<Integer> toPositions(MenuItem i) {
    List<Integer> positions = new LinkedList<>();
    while (i != null) {
        position.addFirst(i.getPosition());
        i = i.getParent();
    }
    return positions;
}
```

Then comparing the position of MenuItem is easy:

```
int compare(MenuItem a, MenuItem b) {
    return comparePosition(toPositions(a), toPositions(b));
}

int comparePosition(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    if (a.isEmpty() && b.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    } else if (a.isEmpty()) {
        return 1;
    } else if (b.isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    } else  {
        int aFirst = a.removeFirst();
        int bFirst = b.removeFirst();
        if (aFirst != bFirst) {
            return aFrist-bFirst;
        } else {
            return comparePosition(a, b);  // compare remaining list
        }
    }
}
```

I believe code can be even shorter for a iterative approach.  Leave it for your practice.

Comment: The logic can be further simplified if your `MenuItem` provides methods like getting number of level for the item, and getting position as on a specific level.  Leave it for your own practice :)