# How to Sort Hierarchical keys of Map Collection?

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, collections

I am facing problem in sorting following key values list(Map). Consider sorting key as expected will solve my problem.

Expected Output

```
Key         Value
1           animal
1.1         dog
1.1.1       tommy
1.1.2       Lily
1.1.10      Sadie
1.2         cat
1.3         camel
1.3.2       camel2
1.3.11      camel11
```

I tried TreeMap but it sorts each character number. what will be used instead there if there is required to sort whole number inside String. I  want something like that as mentioned above in expected output.

```
TreeMap<String, String> data = new TreeMap<String, String>();       
data.put("1",   "animal");
data.put("1.1", "dog");
data.put("1.2", "cat");     
data.put("1.3", "camel");

data.put("1.3.2", "camel2");
data.put("1.3.11", "camel11");

data.put("1.1.1", "tommy");
data.put("1.1.2", "Lily");
data.put("1.1.10", "Sadie");


SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<String>(data.keySet());

System.out.println("Key         Value");

for(String key: keys){
    System.out.println(key+"        "+data.get(key));
```

Actual Output

```
 Key        Value
1       animal
1.1         dog
1.1.1       tommy
1.1.10      Sadie
1.1.2       Lily
1.2         cat
1.3         camel
1.3.11      camel11
1.3.2       camel2
```

Comment: This is caused due to a String sorting. 1.1.10 is smaller than 1.1.2. Maybe try to convert the string to numbers and only than make the comparison? The first solution that comes to my mind is to remove all dots and than sort by integer. Like this: 1110 will be bigger than 112 and your output will be as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Sort entries for table of contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608890/java-sort-entries-for-table-of-contents)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that breaks down the key string by the periods and treats each element as an `int`:

```
public class VersionStringComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        String[] s1parts = s1.split("\\.");
        String[] s2parts = s2.split("\\.");
        int commonLength = Math.min(s1parts.length, s2parts.length);

        // Loop and compare corresponding parts
        for (int i = 0; i < commonLength; ++i) {
            int partCompare = 
                Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(s1parts[i]),
                                Integer.parseInt(s2parts[i]));
            if (partCompare != 0) {
                return partCompare;
            }
        }

        // Out of parts - the shorter array should come first
        return Integer.compare(s1parts.length, s2parts.length);
    }
}
```

This `Comparator` can then be used in a `TreeMap`:

```
TreeMap<String, String> data = new TreeMap<>(new VersionStringComparator());
```

Or a `TreeSet`:

```
TreeSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<>(new VersionStringComparator());
```

Note that this `VersionStringComparator` implementation assumes that it's only applied to strings that look like a series of integers delimited by periods. If you intend to have other strings there, you should add some input validations.

Comment: @aioobe nice trick with recursion there. Took me a minute to understand what you were doing. I wonder if there's any noticeable performance hit from `split`ing multiple times though.

Comment: Your solution work well

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below code, to get the result you expected

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MapSort implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String v1, String v2) {
        String[] a1 = v1.split("\\.");
        String[] a2 = v2.split("\\.");
        int min = 0;
        int max = 0;
        if (a1.length <= a2.length) {
            min = a1.length;
            max = a2.length;
        } else {
            min = a2.length;
            max = a1.length;
        }
        int[] first = new int[max];
        int[] second = new int[max];
        for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
            first[i] = Integer.parseInt(a1[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
            second[i] = Integer.parseInt(a2[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
            if (first[i] != second[i]) {
                return first[i] > second[i] ? 1 : -1;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TreeMap<String, String> data = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        data.put("1", "animal");
        data.put("1.1", "dog");
        data.put("1.2", "cat");
        data.put("1.3", "camel");

        data.put("1.3.2", "camel2");
        data.put("1.3.11", "camel11");

        data.put("1.1.1", "tommy");
        data.put("1.1.2", "Lily");
        data.put("1.1.10", "Sadie");

        Set<String> myset = new TreeSet<>(new MapSort());
        myset.addAll(data.keySet());

        for (String key : myset) {
            System.out.println(key + ":" + data.get(key));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to pass a `Comparator` to your `TreeMap` constructor. Something like:

```
class MyNumComp implements Comparator<String>{

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

        // safely cast Strings to some int-type structure and compare
        // return -1 if s1 < s2; return 0 if equal; else 1

    }
}
```